# I am an Indian citizen working in Germany. Can I travel to Bulgaria without a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, paperwork, bulgaria, german-residents

I am from India, and recently moved to Germany for work. I would like to travel to Bulgaria for a conference next month. Can I go there without a visa as I am a resident in another EU country?

I can't find this information online. Any links/references will be much appreciated.

Comment: Searching for 'visa for Bulgaria' on Google gives me a link to the visa information page from the Bulgarian Ministry of Foreign Affairs as the first search hit. Is any part of your question not answered by what you can find there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Germany for a maximum stay of 90 days

So yes, you can enter without a visa - present your passport and residence permit card at the Bulgarian border.